# How to display a week range v-date-picker range?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vcalendar

I am using [v-calendar](https://github.com/nathanreyes/v-calendar) as a date picker in my Vue project. **My objective is to select complete week** - 7 days fixed from sunday to saturday. I have been looking around in the documentation but unable to get my head around it.

This is what I have as an example
https://codepen.io/achaphiv/pen/OJXjooB

```
<div id='app'>
  <v-date-picker v-model="value" :available-dates="availableDates" is-inline></v-date-picker>
  
  The current date is: {{ value || 'null' }}
</div>


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    const now = new Date()
    const later = new Date(now.getTime() + 5 * 60 * 1000)
    return {
      value: null,
      availableDates: [
        { start: now, end: later }
      ]
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you correctly try like following snippet:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      value: null,
      availableDates: { 
        start: new Date(), 
        end: new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 7)) 
      }
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/v-calendar@1.0"></script>
<div id='app'>
  <v-date-picker v-model="value" :available-dates="availableDates" is-inline></v-date-picker>
  
  The current date is: {{ value || 'null' }}
</div>
```